# Where is the definition of `struct ap_conf_vector_t`?

Tags: c++, c, apache

Where is the definition of the `struct ap_conf_vector_t` in Apache sources? Is it generated, where?

Comment: Err... http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=ap_conf_vector_t? ;-)

Comment: Amusingly, if you do a Google search for `struct ap_conf_vector_t`, this question is the first hit.

Comment: @Christian.K: Have you actually looked at any of the Google search results? I did even before asking this question and **none** contains the answer.

Comment: Yes I [did](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/info/rzaie/APR/http__config_8h.html), but didn't realize it doesn't define `struct ap_conf_vector_t` itself. But mine was merely a comment, hence my smiley and I didn't downvote. Actually, standing corrected and knowing it is not _that_ easy, I'll upvote. However, note that my comment got some "upvotes" and possibly those are the two that downvoted your question. You might want to consider adding a (sadly?) superfluous, albeit necessary it seems, disclaimer like "I did Google and could find" in the future.

Comment: I actually upvoted your comment because you had the restraint to not use LMGTFY :)  I did not downvote the question, because it's a reasonable one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ap_conf_vector_t seems to be an opaque datatype. This is usually used in *the old days* to define a *stable* api which the possibility to later change the implementation without changes to the api.

ap_conf_vector_t is only used as a parameter to the api functions like:

- ap_get_module_config
- ap_parse_htaccess

You are not supposed to manipulate the members of this structure directly. Kind of OO programming, you only can use the supplied functions.

Comment: Ok, even if I am not supposed to manipulate it directly, does the structure have any definition anywhere or is the type never complete anywhere?

Comment: It doesn't have to have a definition, it is never newed or used directly. You just have the pointer to the memory and the api functions. In the implementation it even may be casted to *something completely different*. Think of it as a HANDLE as in Win API.

Answer (score 0):

The definition can be found in http_config.h as follows:

```
    typedef struct ap_conf_vector_t ap_conf_vector_t;
```

It is like void pointer. To understand better, study the following program:

```
    typedef struct generic_struct_for_pointer generic_struct_for_pointer;

    int main(void)
    {
            generic_struct_for_pointer *ptr;

            typedef struct
            {
                    int x,y;
            } position;
     
            position p = {1,2};

            ptr = (generic_struct_for_pointer *) &p;

            return 1;
    }
```